# Float Column Equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compare, equals

I use SQL Server 2005. I have three columns in a table `(ref, column1, column2)`. Columns 1 and 2 are float, `ref` is 1, `column1` is 1000 and `column2`is 1000.

```
select * 
from table 
where ref = 1 and column1 = column2
```

returns 0 row(s)

I converted them to decimal and they are same.

They seem equal but query returns that they are not equal. How could it be possible?

edit:

[Here is the screenshot. They are not same. What causes this and how can i fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZcaA.jpg)

Comment: Show us a few rows of sample data, one of which having your example 1,1000,1000. Also would be helpful to see your DDL for your table.

Comment: Most likely the values are not the same. Run `SELECT CAST(column1 AS binary(8)) AS column1, CAST(column2 AS binary(8)) AS column2 FROM table WHERE ref = 1;`.

Comment: You can try `... where ref = 1 and Abs( column1 - column2 ) < 0.001` to compare the difference to an _iota_. Depending on the range of values, it may make more sense to compare to a fraction of a value rather than an absolute limit, e.g. `Abs( column1 - column2 ) < Abs( column1 * 0.001 )`.

Comment: i added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Float type is an approximation.  The best way to use it in comparing is to first convert it to integer or to decimal:

> CAST(revenue AS NUMERIC(10,2))

Answer (score 0):

But I am getting one row to run the following query. Please check.

```
DECLARE  @TABLE TABLE (REF INT,COLUMN1 FLOAT,COLUMN2 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 1,1000,1000

SELECT * FROM @TABLE WHERE REF = 1 and COLUMN1 = COLUMN2
```

Thanks.